# Regex to split String on pattern but with a minimum number of characters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a long text stored in a String variable following those rules:

1. Split on a dot (.)
2. The Substrings should have a minimum length of 30 (for example).

Take this example:

```
"The boy ate the apple. The sun is shining high in the sky. The answer to life the universe and everything is forty two, said the big computer."
```

let's say the minimum length I want is 30.

The result splits obtained would be:

- "The boy ate the apple. The sun is shining high in the sky."
- "The answer to life the universe and everything is forty two, said the big computer."

I don't want to take "The boy ate the apple." as a split because it's less than 30 characters.

**2 ways I thought of:**

1. Loop through all the characters and add them to a String builder. And whenever I reach a dot (.) I check if my String builder is more than the minimum I split it, otherwise I continue.
2. Split on all dots (.), and then loop through the splits. if one of the Splitted strings is smaller than the minimum, I concatenate it with the one after.

But I am looking if this can be done directly by using a Regex to split and test the minimum number of characters before a match.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using split, you could also match your values using a capturing group. 
To make the dot also match a newline you could use `Pattern.DOTALL`

```
\s*(.{30}[^.]*\.|.+$)
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "\\s*(.{30}[^.]*\\.|.+$)";
```

**Explanation**

- `\s*` Match 0_ times a whitespace character
- `(` Capturing group

  - `.{30}` Match any character 30 times
  - `[^.]*` Match 0+ times not a dot using a negated character class
  - `\.` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `.+$` Match 1+ times any character until the end of the string.
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQDWJa/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UhTS8D)

Comment: Hello, I like this approach, but the last part goes missing if it's under 30 characters. Can this be modified to match the last remaining part (in your java code example the last "Test" is omitted. Doing that by regex or java code works for me. Thanks

Comment: @Youssef If you mean you want to match what comes after without a dot, you could use an alternation. `\s*(.{30}[^.]*\.|[^.]+$)` [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pBtf7M/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/H8prcf)

Comment: I would like to match the last part no matter what it is. If that demo it will match "Test" if it's at the end but it will not match "Test." ( if it has a dot at the end but less than 30 characters). I am trying not to lose the last sentence of the text. If that makes sense

Comment: @Youssef In that case you could change the regex to `\s*(.{30}[^.]*\.|.+$)`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQDWJa/1).  This will match either 30 characters until the first dot or else it will match all.

Comment: It did. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the answer with the comments in case someone is looking for that. Out of curiosity, why does your approach perform way better than the split approach, on long texts?

Comment: I have updated the answer for future readers. Unfortunately I do not have the answer to that, but I did find [this page](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-patternmatcher-versus-stringsplit-stanley-mclenna) which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
"\W*+(.{30,}?)\W*\."
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/aavcme/3

- `\W*+` takes as much as non-word character to trim spaces between sentences
- `.` matches any character (I guess you want to match any kind of character in your sentences)
- `{30,}` asserts the minimum length of the match (30)
- `?` means "as few as possible"
- `\.` matches the dot separating the sentences (assuming that you always have a dot at the end of a sentence, even the last one)

Comment: This solution works but you have to extract the last part manually if it is less than 30 characters long.

Comment: How about this ?  `((.{30,}?\.)+)(.+)?`

Comment: You merge all the sentences with that... just tested it on regex101

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the *split* method, try *matching* with the following regexp: `\S.{29,}?[.]`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CSnbmA/1/)**